# How to use Like Operator with QueryDSL-Web?

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

**Overview**

Using QueryDSL, its possible to derive queries from the attributes contained in a Request query string. For example:

```
?firstname=Dave&lastname=Matthews
```

This query would search for users with firstname equal to Dave and Last name equal to matthews.

**Problem**

How do you use the LIKE operator? For example, suppose I want to fetch a list of users that have the lastname containing the word "Matt". Ive read solutions that propose to bind the fields and instead of using equals, use contains in all of them. This does solve the problem but creates another as it replaces the EQUAL operator. Other proposed solutions is to customize every repository with every possible field of the class, as in : [Querydsl web with contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250550/querydsl-web-with-contains)

**Current solution**

The current solution I have is to search using equals, it does not solve the problem. It does not work with LIKE, CONTAINS, or anything of the sort. So basically I have the method below:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  String index(Model model, 
          @QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate,    
          Pageable pageable) {

    model.addAttribute("users", repository.findAll(predicate, pageable));

    return "index";
  }
```

**Another Topic in Stackoverflow**

The following topic

[How can you use different operators with QueryDSL Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378013/how-can-you-use-different-operators-with-querydsl-web)

Approach a similar issue however using another operators as example. The proposed solution by the user Geert Graat, is to use the library Spring Data QueryDSL Value Operators, which can be found at : https://bitbucket.org/gt_tech/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/src/master/

However, some questions remain:

A) Is it still valid to 2022?

B) Is this the only and proper solution?

**References**

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/query-dsl-web-support.html

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/web-query-dsl-collection-properties.html

https://gt-tech.bitbucket.io/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/README.html

https://bitbucket.org/gt_tech/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/src/master/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe